# Choose sample of numbers from the list...starting with the highest number

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, numbers, sample

I have a list (size varies) of numbers in one column, I would like to select numbers (from that column) and put it in another column, but those selected numbers must be the highest from the list and second condition is this loop stops when sum of selected numbers is larger than 70% of original population. 
If I am not explaining my problem correctly here's the image.

[image]

My solution would be to create temporary column extract largest number, put rest of those numbers in another column, extract second largest, and so on, but that doesn't seem efficient.

If someone has a solution I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

@DougGlancy
This what I was trying to avoid (check below). I know that code below could be more efficient, but generally it is slow, especially when I run it 10-15 times in a row in order to create another sample of data. That's why I answered you about efficiency, because every time I use helper columns in VBA, I get slow results, so I assumed that doing it all in memory would save some, time when executing code.

I hope that you didn't gave me a negative vote just because of that.

```
    Sub Sample20()

Worksheets("Junk2").Range("AA:AD").ClearContents

Dim Mat As Range
Set Mat = Sheets("Mat").Range("E38")
Dim Kto As String
Kto = "20"
Dim Saldo20 As Long
Saldo20 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("BB").Range("D101:D106"))

Dim WSS As Worksheet
Set WSS = Sheets("AN")
Dim WSD As Worksheet
Set WSD = Sheets("Junk2")
Set rRng = WSS.Range("B2:B5000")

Dim col As String
col = "AA"

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = WSD.Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Saldo20 > Mat.Value * 0.7 Then
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    If rCell.Value <> "" Then
    If Left(rCell.Value, 2) = Kto Then
    If Left(rCell.Value, 3) = "209" Or Left(rCell.Value, 3) = "206" Then
    GoTo XX
    Else
    If rCell.Offset(0, 5).Value > 0 Then
        WSD.Range(col & LastRow).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        WSD.Range(col & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        WSD.Range(col & LastRow).Offset(0, 2).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value / 1000
        WSD.Range(col & LastRow).Offset(0, 3).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 5).Value / 1000
       LastRow = LastRow + 1
               End If
               End If
               End If
        End If
XX:
    Next rCell
End If

 Worksheets("Junk2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Worksheets("Junk2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AD1:AD2500") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Worksheets("Junk2").Sort
        .SetRange Range("AA1:AD2500")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Dim rCell1 As Range
Dim rRng1 As Range
Dim LastR As Integer
LastR = Sheets("Junk2").Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim LastR2 As Integer
LastR2 = Sheets("Junk2").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rRng1 = Worksheets("Junk2").Range("AD1:AD" & LastR)

Dim LastRow2 As Long
LastRow2 = Worksheets("Junk2").Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Dim x As Integer
x = 1

sum1 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Junk2").Range("AD1:AD" & LastR)) * 0.7
Dim Sum2 As Long
Sum2 = 0

For Each rCell1 In rRng1.Cells
If Sum2 > sum1 Then
Exit Sub
Else
        Worksheets("Junk2").Range("F" & LastR2).Value = rCell1.Offset(0, -3).Value
        Worksheets("Junk2").Range("G" & LastR2).Value = rCell1.Offset(0, -2).Value
        Worksheets("Junk2").Range("H" & LastR2).Value = rCell1.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Worksheets("Junk2").Range("I" & LastR2).Value = rCell1.Offset(0, 0).Value
        LastR2 = LastR2 + 1
        Sum2 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Junk2").Range("I1:I" & LastR))
        End If
Next rCell1

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this Excel? If so, could you tag your question with that? More important than `numbers` and `sample`

Comment: Turn on the Macro Recorder and try this: 1. Copy the column to another column and sort. 2.Put a formula in the column next to it that gives a cumulative total. 3.Put a formula in a 3rd column that does a Match with a 1 as the last argument, matching the value cumulative total against 70% of the first column total. 4.Delete the cells below the match. 5.Delete the two extra columns. 6. Look at the code. 7. Ask question on SO about that code.

Comment: As I said problem is efficiency. To complete whole operation I have to call a lot of other routines, I really don't want something to slow whole process, but thanks. I think that putting range in array, then sorting numbers in array is more efficient, but I don't know how to remove selected number from array, without emptying it and populating it again without that value. As I said it should be efficient and simple as it could be.

Comment: I assume you are commenting at me above. Try using @DougGlancy if that's true. I'm not sure what your comments on efficiency have to do with my suggestion.

Comment: @DougGlancy I answered you in edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume, your list is B1:B8 and the sum is at B9. Then:

```
D1: =MAX($B$1:$B$8)
D2: =IF(SUM($D$1:D1)<($B$9*0.7),LARGE($B$1:$B$8,ROW()),"")
```

Copy down from D2... it will show the numbers in an descending order until 70% of B9 is reached...

If the list differs in size but the sum is always the biggest number then you can alternatively use:

```
D1: =LARGE($B:$B,2)
D2: =IF(SUM($D$1:D1)<(MAX($B:$B)*0.7),LARGE($B:$B,ROW()+1),"")
```

And again, copy D2 down.

No VBA needed :P

**EDIT**
Because I'm in a really good mood... just use this:

```
Public Function getUpperValues(xNumbers As Variant, xMax As Double) As Variant
  Dim i As Long, xArr() As Variant
  ReDim xArr(1 To Application.Count(xNumbers))
  For i = 1 To UBound(xArr)
    xArr(i) = Application.Large(xNumbers, i)
    If Application.Sum(xArr) >= xMax Then Exit For
  Next
  ReDim Preserve xArr(1 To i)
  getUpperValues = xArr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but VBA is necessary. Situation is much more complicated, image shown above is only a simple example, so that my problem is better understood.

Comment: you know that you could adopt this to vba? pretty easy... also, even it doesn't look good, you always should show some "code" to get best solutions ;)